# Moving directories from one repository to another

Tags: java, git, github, directory, repository

How to move two directories from one repo to another repo having commit history on both directories.

```
FromRep:
  Directory 1
  Directory 2
  Directory 3
  Directory 4

ToRepo:
  Directory 2
  Directory 3
```

I am able to move Dir2 and Dir3 (FromRep to ToRepo) here. I can only see the merged commit history of both directories in ToRepo.
Solution Required:  we also need to see the commit history separately in the corresponding individual directories

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move a subdirectory from a branch in one git repository to a branch in a different repository, preserving history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434290/how-to-move-a-subdirectory-from-a-branch-in-one-git-repository-to-a-branch-in-a)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+move+directory+history+different+repository